# how to sort a list of tuples by first element (string) alphabetically [PYTHON]

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, tuples

I have a list of tuples like this:

```
[('peter':1), ('mary':5), ('anthony':6), ('brandon':4)]
```

if I wanted to sort this list and get something like:

```
[('anthony':6),('brandon':4),('mary':5),('peter':1)]
```

How could I sort this in python ?

Comment: That's not a list of tuples … or valid Python.

Comment: why not? @ZeroPiraeus

Comment: Try typing it into a Python interpreter.

Comment: I fixed it, it was a mistyping @ZeroPiraeus

Comment: No, you didn't.

Comment: Please don't try to "fix" OP's question; for all we know, given what they've entered here, they might actually have a dictionary or something else.

Comment: @Mohsin Please do **not** fix syntax errors in question code, or make any edits that change the meaning of the posted code. It _might_ be a mere typo, but it _could_ be an important factor in the OP's problem. On SO, we don't edit people's problems away, we attempt to clarify them in comments.

Comment: @Mohsin were you talking about this fact that I closed the list with '}' ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Zero points out, your example data isn't valid, but I presume this is simply a typing issue. So providing the data *is* valid and looks like:

```
my_data = [('peter',1), ('mary',5), ('anthony',6), ('brandon',4)]
```

You could use either

```
sorted_data = sorted(my_data)
```

or:

```
my_data.sort()
```

Comment: Assuming OP has an actual list of tuples, the `key` argument is unnecessary. `sorted()` sorts lexicographically by default.

Comment: `my_data.sort()` returns `None` (at least in Python 3), which doesn't seem to be what was wanted. `sorted(my_data)` works.

Answer (score 4):

To sort your list in place, just [`sort()`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting) it :

```
>>> lst = [('peter',1), ('mary',5), ('anthony',6), ('brandon',4)]
>>> lst.sort()
>>> lst
[('anthony', 6), ('brandon', 4), ('mary', 5), ('peter', 1)]
```

It will sort the tuples by their first element (the name). If two names are the same, they will be sorted by their second element (the id). See ["Lexicographical order"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).

If you have a `dict`, you can get a sorted list of tuples this way :

```
>>> dct = {'peter': 1, 'mary': 5, 'anthony':6, 'brandon':4}
>>> sorted(dct.items())
[('anthony', 6), ('brandon', 4), ('mary', 5), ('peter', 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean to say this:

```
z = [('peter',1), ('mary',5), ('anthony',6), ('brandon',4)]
```

You can try:

```
from operator import itemgetter
sorted(z, key = itemgetter(0))
```

Or:

```
sorted(z, key = lambda x: x[0])
```

Or:

```
z.sort(key = lambda x: x[0])
```

In case you are referring to a dictionary which would look like this:

```
z1 = {'peter':1, 'mary':5, 'anthony':6, 'brandon':4}
```

Dictionaries are inherently order-less and sorting dictionaries does not makes sense. We use keys to reference dictionary elements, thus the order would not matter.

You can refer to http://sthurlow.com/python/lesson06/ for inherent differences between a list, tuple and dictionary.